# Import csv with incorrect data into SQL Server by SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, split, str-replace, sqlbulkcopy

I have to try to import delimited files via C# into a SQL Server database using `SqlBulkCopy`. I use `StreamReader` for reading the data from the flat file and a `DataTable` for writing it to the database using `SqlBulkCopy`.

Unfortunately within the various fields delimited by the `;` we do not always have correct data, so we need to make corrections to the values we read, such as removing single quotes or replacing non-existent dates with real dates, or replace `,` with `.` for float number:

```
string[] line = reader.ReadLine().Split(';');

line[0] = line[0].Trim().Replace("'", "");
...
...

line[n] = line[n].Trim().Replace(",", ".");

DataTable.Row.Add(line);
```

I'm noticing though that in doing the replace and other operations on string arrays the performance is really really bad.

Can anyone suggest the most efficient way to do this kind of load?

Comment: Have you considered writing a method to process the `reader.ReadLine()` to perform the split, trim, and replace in one pass of the string? As it is, there are multiple passes to process each of those separately. If such a method were created, use a `StringBuilder` to construct the new string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder

Comment: Could you do some examples, please? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of the raw data? Is the number of columns known and constant?

Comment: I' have date in yyyymmdd fomat, double number with "," rather than "." for decimal position, could I have no data between two delmiter ";".